# Comparing and splitting of string inside JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, string

I have a string in a variable:

```
var test= "http://www.gmail.com@%@http://www.google.com@%@http://www.yahoo.com@%@";
```

I want to split this string at the occurrences of the special characters, ie: `@%@`, then after splitting I want to push this thing to an array like this:

```
var spcds = [];
    spcds.push("http://www.gmail.com");
 spcds.push("http://www.google.com");
 spcds.push("http://www.yahoo.com");
```

What I need is just split the string variable and push that to the `spcds` array. How can I do this in my JavaScript function such that the resultant values will be stored to another variable which I then push to the array `spcds`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [`split` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) to split the string:

```
var parts = test.split("@%@");
```

And if you don’t want to have empty parts, use the [`filter` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to filter out the values that are not an empty string:

```
var parts = test.split("@%@").filter(function(val){return val!="";});
```

Answer (score 1):

This will give you an array of the strings you are after Then you can just iterate through the array as needed.

```
var mySplitResult = myString.split("@%@");
```

Answer (score 1):

this should give you the array you want:

```
var testarray= 
    ("http://www.gmail.com@%@http://www.google.com@%@http://www.yahoo.com@%@")
     .split('@%@');
```